# How to add tables relations into custom entities content type?

Tags: entities, 8

I have a custom content entities in my Shop module.

I want 2 tables :

- Orders
- Order line

I create a custom content entity for orders, but I ask about the way to do the order line.

Do I need to create a second custom entity content and make a field reference orders table inside?

Or there is a way to declare subTable into the main entitie (orders for me)?

Comment: Make the items as fields and attach it to the order entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, forget about tables. Drupal 8 mostly takes care of that for entities.

Think about data structures instead: entities and fields.

What do you want?

- Two separate entities, both possibly extensible with additional fields, maybe different bundles (e.g. product and shipping line items). Then make two entity types, with a reference field from line items to the order.
- Simpler, non-extensible line items. Then you can design them as a custom field type and add that as a base field with unlimited cardinality. (In this case, they will be stored in a separate table, but you don't need to know about that for the most part).